# How to write a test class for task

Tags: apex, trigger, unit-test, community, tasks

Hi friends i got a requirement to restrict deletion of tasks for some profiles.So, i wrote a trigger with test class.It shows 100% code coverage but when i move to production it shows code coverage failure.

My requirement whenever calltype is not null.they can't delete task except system admin & other profile

Please tell me where is the problem.Is it required to handle Lead & opportunity & account separately.Please specify

For reference:

```
trigger TaskDeletion on Task (before delete) 
{
List<Profile> profiles=[select id from Profile where name='System 
                        Administrator' or name='Sales Manager No IP 
                        restriction'];
String ProfileId = UserInfo.getProfileId();  
for (Task a : Trigger.old)  
{
   if ( a.CallType !=null && (profileId <> profiles[0].id || profileId <> profiles[1].id) )
   {
   a.addError('You can\'t delete this record');
   }
}
}
```

Test Class

```
@isTest
public class TestTaskDeletion 
{
static testMethod void testStandardUserwithTask() 
{
    Profile standardProf = [select id from profile where name='Standard 
                             User'];
    User su = new User(alias = 'standt',         
    email='standarduser@azugatask.com',emailencodingkey='UTF- 
                                 8',FirstName='task',

        lastname='testing',languagelocalekey='en_US',localesidkey='en_US',profileid = standardProf.Id,
                       timezonesidkey='America/Los_Angeles',username='standarduser@azugatask.com');
    System.runAs(su) 
    {
        Account a = new Account(name='Testtask');
        insert a;
        List<Task> tasks = new List<Task>{};
            for(Integer i = 0; i < 200; i++) 
        {
            Task t = new Task(Subject='Donni'+i,Status='New',Priority='Normal',CallType='Outbound');
            tasks.add(t);
        }
        test.startTest();
        insert tasks;
        test.stopTest();
        // Verify the "You can\'t delete this record" error is thrown whenever they tries to delete a task
        Boolean errorThrown = false;
        try 
        {
            delete tasks;
        } 
        catch (Exception e) 
        {
            System.debug(e);
            if (e.getMessage().contains('You can\'t delete this record')) 
            {
                errorThrown = true;
            }
        }
        System.assert(errorThrown);
    }

}
   static testMethod void testAdminUserwithTask() {

    // Next make sure that a System Admin *can* delete an attachment
    Profile adminProf = [select id from profile where name='System Administrator']; 
        User au = new User(alias = 'Admint', email='AdminUser@azugatask.com',emailencodingkey='UTF-8',FirstName='Admin',
                       lastname='task',languagelocalekey='en_US',localesidkey='en_US',profileid = adminProf.Id,
                       timezonesidkey='America/Los_Angeles',username='AdminUser@azugatask.com');
    // Switch current user to System Admin user
    System.runAs(au) {

        // Create test data (a new Account with an Attachment)
        Account a = new Account(Name='Testtasking');
        insert a;
        List<Task> tasks = new List<Task>{};
            for(Integer i = 0; i < 200; i++) 
        {
            Task t = new Task(Subject='Donni'+i,Status='New',Priority='Normal',CallType='Outbound');
            tasks.add(t);
        }
        test.startTest();
        insert tasks;
        test.stopTest();
        // Verify that no error is thrown when the attachment is deleted
        Boolean errorThrown = false;
        try {
            delete tasks;
        } catch (Exception e) {
            System.debug(e);
            errorThrown = true;
        }
        System.assert(errorThrown);
        //System.assertEquals('true',errorThrown);
    }
}

}
```

Comment: Code coverage in production is not just related to one class.Can you check what is the current overall code coverage on production?

Comment: Overall 93% code coverage.@Abhijeet

Comment: @Pavantej You need to first insert the user before doing 'System.runAs'. (I don't know if it's the issue, but still.. ;) )

Comment: Hey sorry it's working now.I thought test class also added automatically if we select dependencies but now i added manually test class to change set.